# How to Detect Maximize event on multi-monitor system

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

On windows, C/C++ how do I detect the "maximize event" on WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message when the system has multiple monitors? That is, when the window is maximized on any display?

(Code for other operating systems is also welcome!)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to detect all displays using [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [EnumDisplaySettingsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
// C/C++ solution for enumerating display settings.

// Struct for display properties
struct DisplayProps
{
    int x, y;   // only display position is needed..
};

DISPLAY_DEVICE disp;
DISPLAY_DEVICE adapter;
DEVMODE mode;
DisplayProps the_displays[32];  // Array to store the results.
int i = 0, j = 0, display_count = 0;

// Initialize win32 structs.
memset(&disp, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
disp.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
memset(&args.adapter, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
adapter.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
memset(&mode, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
mode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

memset(the_displays, 0, sizeof(the_displays));

// adapter loop:
while(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &adapter, 0))
{   // multiple displays on single adapter loop:
    j = 0;
    while(EnumDisplayDevices((TCHAR*)&adapter.DeviceName, j, &disp, 0))
    {   
        // The device must be active, attached to desktop and not a mirroring device.
        if((disp.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
            && (disp.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
            && !(disp.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER))
        {
            // read display settings.
            if(EnumDisplaySettingsEx((TCHAR*)&adapter.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &mode, 0))
            {
                the_displays[display_count].x = mode.dmPosition.x;
                the_displays[display_count].y = mode.dmPosition.y;
                ++display_count;
            }

        }
        // Reset
        memset(&args.disp, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
        disp.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
        ++j;
    }
    // Reset
    memset(&args.adapter, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
    adapter.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    ++i;
}
```

Then on WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message in window procedure we need to actualy detect the event. This requires an possibly undocumented value SWP_STATECHANGED (0x8000) and use of [AdjustWindowRectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
WINDOWPOS * wp = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
if( (wp->flags & (SWP_STATECHANGED | SWP_FRAMECHANGED)) != 0)
{
    // Figuring next part was a bit of luck involved: I noticed that AdjustWindowRectEx rect.left
    // matches window position (x and y) on default display when window is maximized
    RECT styleadj = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    // Can't cache/save this because user can change the theme.
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&styleadj,
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, /* your window dwStyle */
    false, /* not using menu? */
    WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE); /* your window dwExStyle */ 

    for(int i = 0; i < the_display_count; ++i)
    {
        if((wp->x == the_displays[i].x + styleadj.left) && (wp->y == the_displays[i].y + styleadj.left))
        {
            // Event is detected, do what ever you want!
            MessageBox(NULL, "A Maximize event Detected.", "Event Detected!", MB_OK);
        }
    }
}
```

I have **confirmed** that this code works on multiple displays (I have two) and with Windows 7 Aero Glass theme, Aero Basic theme, and old win 2000 theme. WinXp and 8 are untested. [AdjustWindowRectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does indeed return diffrent values on diffrent themes.

Answer (score 1):

When window is to get maximized, esp. as a result of interactive user action, it receives `WM_SYSCOMMAND` [`SC_MAXIMIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Maximization process typically involves [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, handling which...

> An application can use this message to override the window's default maximized size and position, or its default minimum or maximum tracking size.

To detect current monitor work area coordinates perhaps the easiest is `MonitorFromRect` API:

```
HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(&rcCenter, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
if(hMonitor)
{
    MONITORINFO MonitorInfo = { sizeof MonitorInfo };
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &MonitorInfo);
    // NOTE: MonitorInfo.rcWork is what you look for
```