# Determine available display resolutions in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, desktop-application, screen-resolution

in Windows and other desktop operating systems is always a combo box in the display settings showing all available display resolutions.

I need this kind of combo box in Qt or C++ and I'm stuck.

I found a C# approach here: [How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744609/5251010)

I found a C++ approach: [How to Detect Maximize event on multi-monitor system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668391/5251010)

MSDN says within [EnumDisplaySettingsEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162612(VS.85).aspx) docu that all display resolutions can be obtained by iterate over the argument iModeNum:

> Graphics mode indexes start at zero. To obtain information for all of a display device's graphics modes, make a series of calls to EnumDisplaySettingsEx, as follows: Set iModeNum to zero for the first call, and increment iModeNum by one for each subsequent call. Continue calling the function until the return value is zero.

I've modified the C++ approach to receive my goal in Windows:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_DISPLAY_WIDTH 0
#define DEFAULT_DISPLAY_HEIGHT 0
#define DEFAULT_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY 60
#define DEFAULT_DISPLAY_SOURCE 0

struct DisplayResolution
{
    DisplayResolution( int _width = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_WIDTH,
                       int _height = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_HEIGHT,
                       int _frequency = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY,
                       int _defaultSource = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_SOURCE )
    {
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        frequency = _frequency;
        defaultSource = _defaultSource;
    }

    int width;
    int height;
    int frequency;
    int defaultSource;

};

typedef std::vector<DisplayResolution>::iterator DisplayResolutionIterator;

std::vector<DisplayResolution> getAvailableDisplayResolutions( )
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE disp;
    DISPLAY_DEVICE adapter;
    DEVMODE mode;
    std::vector<DisplayResolution> displayResolutions;
    int i = 0, j = 0, display_count = 0, k = 0;

    // Initialize win32 structs.
    memset(&disp, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
    disp.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    memset(&adapter, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
    adapter.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    memset(&mode, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
    mode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

    //memset(the_displays, 0, sizeof(the_displays));

    // adapter loop:
    while(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &adapter, 0))
    {   // multiple displays on single adapter loop:
        j = 0;
        qDebug() << (TCHAR*)&adapter.DeviceName;
        while(EnumDisplayDevices((TCHAR*)&adapter.DeviceName, j, &disp, 0))
        {
            // The device must be active, attached to desktop and not a mirroring device.
            if((disp.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
                && (disp.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
                && !(disp.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER))
            {
                // read display settings.
                k = 0;
                while(EnumDisplaySettingsEx((TCHAR*)&adapter.DeviceName, k, &mode, 0))
                {
                    displayResolutions.push_back( DisplayResolution(mode.dmPelsWidth,
                                                                    mode.dmPelsHeight,
                                                                    mode.dmDisplayFrequency,
                                                                    mode.dmDefaultSource) );
                    // Reset
                    memset(&mode, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
                    mode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
                    ++display_count;
                    ++k;
                }

            }
            // Reset
            memset(&disp, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
            disp.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
            ++j;
        }
        // Reset
        memset(&adapter, 0, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
        adapter.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
        ++i;
    }
    return displayResolutions;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::vector<DisplayResolution> displayResolutions = getAvailableDisplayResolutions( );

    DisplayResolutionIterator it = displayResolutions.begin();
    DisplayResolutionIterator itEnd = displayResolutions.end();
    for( it; it != itEnd; ++it )
    {
        printf( "Resolution: " );
        printf( "%i x %i", (*it).width, (*it).height );
        printf( " (%iHz)", (*it).frequency );
        printf( " @Source:%i", (*it).defaultSource );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Hopefully it helps people in Windows reading this, but Unix?

I know one method within Qt but this will only collect the current display resolution via [QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry).

Has Qt a method to receive all available display resolutions?

Kind regards,
Pixtar

Comment: If you run on X11, then there are X-specific mechanisms for that. For everything else, you'll need a backend-specific approach.

Comment: So you mean something like [XOpenDisplay](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xopendisplay) and [DefaultScreenOfDisplay](https://linux.die.net/man/3/defaultscreenofdisplay). As far as I've understand it - this will give me only access to the current display resolution, but not to all available resolutions.

Comment: That only gives you the current resolution. Anyway, that's a separate question - perhaps search and you'll find it already asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Qt doesn't provide any APIs with such information. You can get the *current* resolution of a given screen via `QScreen:geometry()`. But there's no Qt way to get a list of available resolutions, nor to switch them.

You need to look for platform-specific questions about it, and ask them if they don't exist. One question should cover one platform.